# Error when using IF ELSE

Tags: windows, batch-file, syntax, syntax-error

I am writing this script and everything was working flawlessly until I add the if else portion... Then it returns The syntax of the commands is incorrect

If I remove it, poof, it works. If I try keeping the if else and change the cone inside to just an echo, poof, also works. So I am not sure what may be the problem and how to properly debug it...

```
@echo off

:: The only thing that normally needs to be changed is the Type variable. It should match the folder name where the .bak files are stored.
set Type=DAILY

set Datum=%date:~0,4%%date:~5,2%%date:~8,2%
set Folder=C:\SQLBKP\
set Flag=%Folder%\%Type%\backup_ready.flg
set ZIPFILE=%Folder%\%Type%-backup-%Datum%.zip
set SrcFolder=%Folder%\%Type%
set Passphrase=passwd
set BUCKET=bucket
@echo on

IF exist %Flag% (
    :start

    cd %Folder%

    del %ZIPFILE%
    del %ZIPFILE%.gpg

    "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a %ZIPFILE% "%SrcFolder%"

    "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" t %ZIPFILE% | FIND "Everything is Ok" && goto continue || blat -to backupalerts@foo.com -server mail.protection.outlook.com -f backupalerts@foo.com -subject "%Type% backup integrity check failed on %computername%" -body "This script detected that the %Type% integrity check of the zipped folder failed on the machine %computername%."
    exit

    :continue
    @gpg --batch --passphrase %Passphrase% -c %ZIPFILE%

    aws s3 cp %ZIPFILE%.gpg s3://%BUCKET%/prefix/ || blat -to backupalerts@foo.com -server mail.protection.outlook.com -f backupalerts@foo.com -subject "%Type% backup failed on %computername%" -body "This script detected that the %Type% upload of the zipped folder to the S3 bucket failed on the machine %computername%." & exit

    del %Folder%\%Type%\*.bak
    del %ZIPFILE%
    del %ZIPFILE%.gpg

    exit

) ELSE (
    timeout /t 600 

    goto start
)
```

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: As suggested by Margoo I was able to fix it by removing all the code from the if code block and calling it with `CALL :label`.

Now it looks like this:

```
goto ifelse

:start
cd %Folder%

del %ZIPFILE%
del %ZIPFILE%.gpg

"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a %ZIPFILE% "%SrcFolder%"

"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" t %ZIPFILE% | FIND "Everything is Ok" && goto continue || blat -to backupalerts@foo.com -server mail.protection.outlook.com -f backupalerts@foo.com -subject "%Type% backup integrity check failed on %computername%" -body "This script detected that the %Type% integrity check of the zipped folder failed on the machine %computername%."
exit

:continue
@gpg --batch --passphrase %Passphrase% -c %ZIPFILE%

aws s3 cp %ZIPFILE%.gpg s3://%BUCKET%/prefix/ || blat -to backupalerts@foo.com -server mail.protection.outlook.com -f backupalerts@foo.com -subject "%Type% backup failed on %computername%" -body "This script detected that the %Type% upload of the zipped folder to the S3 bucket failed on the machine %computername%." & exit

del %Folder%\%Type%\*.bak
del %ZIPFILE%
del %ZIPFILE%.gpg

exit


:ifelse
IF exist %Flag% (
    call :begin

) ELSE (
    timeout /t 600 
    call :begin
)
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is output after entering `%DATE%` in your Command prompt.

Comment: Do not attempt to use labels within a code block (parenthesised series of lines) - tragedy will follow. Call subroutines instead and use labels there to your heart's content. (`call .?` from the prompt for documentation)

Comment: Compo, the output is 20170925, the "Short date" format has to be set to yyyy-MM-dd on the region settings for it to work.

Comment: Margoo, I will go through the documentation to see if I can make it work, thanks!